# not letting me use .include? (trying to write ruby game)

Tags: ruby, include, nomethoderror

I'm trying to write a text-based ruby game, and I can't figure out what's not allowing my code to use the .includes? method.

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
game.rb:31:in `home': undefined method `includes?' for "run":String (NoMethodError)
    from game.rb:20:in `call'
    from game.rb:20:in `play'
    from game.rb:69:in `<main>'
```

If I use the if move == "run" method, it works fine, but when I do include? this error pops up. I'm not sure why it lets me do == but not .includes?

This is my main game.rb code:

```
require './levels'
include Levels

class Game
  def initialize(start)
    @quips = [
        "You died. Noob.",
        "Nice job, you lost.",
        "Looooooserrrrr."
        ]
    @start = start
  end

  def play
    next_room = @start

    while true
      puts "\n---------"
      room = method(next_room)
      next_room = room.call
    end
  end

  def home
    home_text

    puts "    Do you run out to see what's going on or stay inside and hope the problem goes away?"

    prompt; move = gets.chomp

    if move.includes? "run"
      return :town
    else
      die("Your house catches on fire and collapses on you.")
    end
  end
end

a_game = Game.new(:home).play
```

and my other file levels.rb is this:

```
module Levels

    def prompt
      puts
      print "    > "
    end

    def die(why)
      puts
      puts "    #{why} #{@quips[rand(@quips.length)]}"
      Process.exit(1)
    end

    def bad_input
      puts <<-TEXT
      Learn to follow instructions!
      TEXT
      return :die
    end

    def home_text
      puts <<-TEXT
      You wake up to the smell of smoke in your room. Jolting up from your bed, you 
      look around the room and see a heavy cloud of smoke covering your ceiling. There
      are piercing sounds of screaming outside, coupled with terrorizing roars and howls.

      TEXT
    end
end
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `includes?` in your code. The method is `include?` (no 's')